# MySQLi Fetch Object

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

Is it ok if you do

```
$TEST = $LINK->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
while($ROW = $TEST->fetch_object() && $MAX_ROWS < 16){
  $MAX_ROWS++;
  //more code
}
```

I know you can just add Limit 0,16 to the end of the query, but I was wondering if this syntax works because it seemed to fail.

Sorry I'm just trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: yeah, it´s kinda reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: What fails? What does `$LINK->error` say?  Is `$MAX_ROWS` initialized to 0?  This looks like it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (some brackets added):

```
$TEST = $LINK->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
while(($ROW = $TEST->fetch_object()) && $MAX_ROWS < 16){
  $MAX_ROWS++;
  //more code
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but why would you need the brackets, shouldn't the && show its a new thing after that?

Comment: No, PHP will think you mean this: $var = (fetch && max_rows), the && bounds stronger than the "="

Comment: whats $var end up being after something like that?

Comment: ohhh so $var ends up being the result of fetch && max_rows?

Comment: because when you use $ROW->id or whatever, it would fail because $ROW equals true, wow thanks I was pulling my hair out lol

Comment: no problem ;) please set the answer as solved via the green hook

Comment: No problem :D i was waiting for the 11 minute thing.

Answer (score 0):

> I know you can just add Limit 0,16 to the end of the query, but I was wondering if this syntax works because it seemed to fail.

That should just work. Did it fail with an error?

```
<?php
$max_rows = 0;
$test = true;
while( $test && $max_rows < 16 ) {
   $max_rows++;
   // rest.
}
```

That works for me and should result in the same?

*EDIT*: Tobiask is right. If you use "$row = mysqli_fetch_object( $result ) && $max_rows < 16 )" the content of $row will be true, as both tests are successful.